# Should I only send keys as websafe strings over HTTP in Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, key, google-cloud-datastore

What is the best way to handle `Datastore` keys? Should they only be transferred in websafe format or can I use their `Key Name`? Websafe format is 2-3 times more the amount of characters i.e increasing the ingress/egress costs of Google App Engine. Is it the best and safest approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name used to create the `Key` object is by itself websafe (for example if the key is created using a long or a UUID) then there is no need to use the websafe version. If however it is created using an unsafe name string e.g `Key.create(Custom.class, "John Doe")` then using `key.getName()` over http will cause problems and `.toWebsafeString()` is here for that exact purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To identify an entity (assuming no ancestors) you just need the entity kind and the entity id/name.  Often the context of your app makes it clear what the entity kind is so all you need to know to get the entity is the id/name.

So yes, you can pass only an id/name between backend and frontend, and I do it all the time.

Comment: I'm afraid you've missed the point of the question. I don't have a problem accessing Datastore information. The problem is that I am not sure on how to handle entity keys in my application level. Should the backend and frontend communicate *only* with keys in websafe string form or is it ok to send the key name which is shorter and produces less egress and ingress?

Comment: I didn't miss the point of your question, but I clarified my answer for you.

Comment: Alright so then there is no point in naming the websafe strings "websafe" since both versions of the Keystring are safe over http right?

Comment: Actually I think I got why they are called websafe. A `Key` can be created using any type of name. I for example was giving a UUID as a name which is websafe by itself but someone else might give a non safe string containing spaces and non http-safe characters, that's why there is also a websafe version producer.